# Add empty space in Arabic language string

Tags: ios, swift, arabic, arabic-support

I am trying to add empty space in the string but after adding it spaces are not showing and If I check the length of String it shows different spaces are there but spaces are not there in display

below is my code and screenshot of the same.

```
    let apple = "apple"
    var arabictext = "بيتزا صغيرة بالجبنة‎"

    // here space works
    let ababictextWithSpace = "\(apple)      \(arabictext)"
    print(ababictextWithSpace)

    // here space not work
    var ababictextWithSpace2 = "      \(arabictext)     "
    print(arabictext)




    let str = String(data: arabictext.data(using: .utf8)!, encoding: .utf8)
    print("\(str!)".count)
    print("    \(str!)".count)
```

> Screenshot with output.

[image]

Comment: It'll work fine in device, as in console even Multi-line didn't work.

Comment: It also not working on device 

Answer (score 2):

you can try wrapping your string with (""") [image]

Comment: Issue is with Arabic language, you can use text from question to check.

Comment: I've updated my image, is that what you wanna show?

Comment: You text this in Xcode or in playground ?, plz check this in xocde

Comment: Updated image again, I think that might work for your expectation

Comment: Thanks. Tabs are working but tabs have more space then single space char, actually I want to align this string very precisely so I need to manage by spaces else with tabs string will not be aligned in proper way.

Comment: Hmm for a single space, I don't really know what should we do. 
But I believe there should be other workarounds with that besides adding hardcoded "space"

Answer (score 0):

[image: In my case]

Maybe it's console's bug. 
In fact they're different, the thing that's different size just proof that.